# Dirichlet's composition of a binary quadratic form multiple times: $f \circ f \circ f$.

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

For an integer binary quadratic form $f(x,y) = A_1 x^2 + B_1 xy + C_1 y^2$ (or just $f = (A_1,B_1,C_1)$ for short), and another binary quadratic form $g = (A_2,B_2,C_2)$ with the same discriminant $(B_1^2 - 4A_1 C_1 = B_2^2 - 4A_2 C_2)$, Dirichlet showed that there exists integers $a,A,b,h$ such that there are equivalent forms
$$f \sim F = (a,b,Ah),$$
$$g \sim G = (A,b,ah),$$
and their "composition" (equivalent to Guass's composition) is the class of forms given by
$$(a,b,Ah) \circ (A,b,ah) \sim (Aa,b,h).$$

---

My question is regarding calculating the composition of a form multiple times with itself. For example: $f \circ f \circ f$.

Will there always exist integers $a,b,h$ such that
$$f \sim F = (a,b,a^2 h),$$
$$F^2 \sim F \circ F \sim (a,b,a^2 h) \circ (a,b,a^2 h) \sim (a^2,b,ah),$$
$$F^3 \sim F^2 \circ F \sim (a^2,b,ah) \circ (a,b,a^2 h) \sim (a^3,b,h) \ ?$$

I *think* this is equivalent to asking:

- Does every binary quadratic form have an equivalent quadratic form in the form $(a,b,a^2 h)$? (From which I think everything would follow.)

And for the more general case of composition more times: $f \circ f \circ ... \circ f$

- Does every binary quadratic form have an equivalent quadratic form in the form $(a,b,a^n h)$ for any positive integer $n$?

Comment: Nice overview of Dirichlet and Gauss composition (also touches on ideals and Bhargava cubes): https://dms.umontreal.ca/~revealed/App12A.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes.  In  **primitive** $\langle a,b,c \rangle$    wishing to move to some $\langle a,b_1,c_1 a,$   we do need $\gcd(a,b) = 1$  Then the standard linear change
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1& r \\
0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
gives us $\langle a,b + 2ar,c + br + a r^2 \rangle$
Our first step is to solve $$ c + br + a r^2  \equiv 0 \pmod a$$  or
$$ c + br   \equiv 0 \pmod a$$

Since there are constants with $ma + bn = 1,$ we see $bn \equiv 1 \pmod a$  Then $-cnb \equiv - c \pmod a,$   and we use $r = -cn$
Meanwhile, $b + 2ar \equiv b \pmod a $ and is still coprime with $a$

So far, we have $\langle a,b_1,a c_1 \rangle.$  Next step $\langle a, b_1 + 2at,ac_1 + b_1t + a t^2 \rangle.$   To keep the third coefficient divisible by $a$  we need to take $t = a u,$   so the result will be $\langle a, b_1 + 2a^2u,ac_1 + ab_1u + a^3 u^2 \rangle.$  We want
$$ac_1 + ab_1u + a^3 u^2  \equiv 0 \pmod {a^2},  $$
$$ac_1 + ab_1u   \equiv 0 \pmod {a^2},  $$
$$a(c_1 + b_1u)   \equiv 0 \pmod {a^2},  $$
$$c_1 + b_1u   \equiv 0 \pmod a.  $$
We can solve this because $b_1$  is still invertible $\pmod a$

For example, with disriminant $-47,$   we see that the principal genus is cyclic by putting a $9$ in the middle,

$$\langle 1,9,32 \rangle.$$
$$\langle 2,9,16 \rangle.$$
$$\langle 4,9,8 \rangle.$$
$$\langle 8,9,4 \rangle.$$
$$\langle 16,9,2 \rangle.$$
NOTE
$$\langle 32,9,1 \rangle\sim \langle 1,-9,32 \rangle\sim \langle 1,9,32 \rangle$$

It is harder to see things with indefinite forms. For discriminant $257$  we have class number exactly three,
$$\langle 1,15,-8 \rangle.$$
$$\langle 2,15,-4 \rangle.$$
$$\langle 4,15,-2 \rangle.$$
For one thing, there  are integer solutions to $x^2 + 15 xy - 8 y^2 = -1,$   which can be confirmed by finding the full Gauss-Lagrange cycle of the individual form,

```
jagy@gost:~/Desktop/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle 1 15 -8

  0  form              1          15          -8


           1           0
           0           1

To Return  
           1           0
           0           1

0  form   1 15 -8   delta  -1     ambiguous  
1  form   -8 1 8   delta  1
2  form   8 15 -1   delta  -15
3  form   -1 15 8   delta  1     ambiguous            -1 composed with form zero  
4  form   8 1 -8   delta  -1
5  form   -8 15 1   delta  15
6  form   1 15 -8


  form   1 x^2  + 15 x y  -8 y^2 

minimum was   1rep   x = 1   y = 0 disc 257 dSqrt 16  M_Ratio  256
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-33  -512
-64  -993
=========================================
```